# RDP internal error 0x4 after entering user name and password on Win 11

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-11

I have win 11 machine form which I am trying to RDP server 2019. Once I enter user name and password I get following error.

[image]

The same server is connecting form my old laptop running win 10.

I have tried changing registry settings, change the setting of RDP experiences, group plolicy for system cryptography but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, On win 11 machine the client encryption setting was not enable and causing the issue.

All I need to do is to enable the TLS protocol. I have used IISCrypto to enable this.

[image]